# Javascript performance using the event properties vs using the element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

In Javascript/Jquery what is faster/better. Using the event properties as such:

```
$('#aPQD_Employer').on('change', function(e){
    (e.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].label == "Other")?
        $('#aPQD_EmployerOtherDIV').show()
        :
        $('#aPQD_EmployerOtherDIV').hide();
});
```

VS

```
$('#aPQD_Employer').on('change', function(e){
    ($('#aPQD_Employer').find(":selected").text() == "Other")?
        $('#aPQD_EmployerOtherDIV').show()
        :
        $('#aPQD_EmployerOtherDIV').hide();    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please show the HTML - what is an option.label?

It is not recommended to use a side effect of a ternary in my opinion

Also use .toggle():

```
$('#aPQD_Employer').on('change', function(){
  $('#aPQD_EmployerOtherDIV').toggle(this.value=="Other") 
});
```

If you must use the text, you can use

```
.toggle($("option:selected", this).text()=="Other");
```